# Java File I/O String All Stuck Together No New Lines

Tags: java, file-io

I have a variable filelist.

```
filelist = "Example 1\n Example 2\n"
```

When I do `System.out.println(filename)` I get:

```
"Example 1

Example 2"
```

but when I write to a txt file I get:

```
"Example 1 Example 2"
```

How do I make these start on a newline at \n ?

```
try {
        TextFile = new Formatter("C:\\Text.txt");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        TextFile.format("%s", filename);
        TextFile.close();
    }
```

Comment: Try replacing "\n" with result from `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're running on Windows, which uses `\r\n` as a line separator by default. (As in, that's what programs such as Notepad interpret as a line separator.)

You could hard-code that, or fetch the platform-specific one from the system properties:

```
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Or use `BufferedWriter` (or similar) which provide methods to write a new line - again, using the platform-specific default line separator.